# Overlay ActionBar with sliding drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, slidingdrawer

Is it possible to overlay the actionbar with one specific view(i.e sliding drawer)? I know i can make the whole activity full screen and put the action bar on top of it, but i need to slide a sliding drawer on top of the action bar.

Comment: So basically you need to put something on top of your tabs ? or on top of the action bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can now layout the action bar as a "toolbar" which behaves in the layout just as any other view, and then you can overlay other views (Using frame layouts, drawer layouts etc).

See the section in here about toolbar:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

> As Toolbar is just a ViewGroup, you can style and position it however you want.
>   Then in your Activity or Fragment, set the Toolbar to act as your Action Bar: